# Let $B(x) = \left\{b^t \ | \ t \in \mathbb{Q} ,\ x \in \mathbb{R} \land t \leq x \ \right\}$. Prove that $b^r = \sup B(r)$ if $r$ is rational.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $B(x) = \left\{b^t \ | \  t \in \mathbb{Q} ,\ x \in \mathbb{R} \land t \leq x \  \right\}$. Prove that $b^r = \sup B(r)$ if $r$ is rational.

This was my proof:

**Proof:**

It is clear that $b^r = \max\{B(r)\}$, and is this an upper bound of $B(r)$

The set of all upper bounds of $B(r)$ is

$$U(r) = \left\{x \ | \ x \geq b^r\ \land x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

It thus follows that any $x < b^r$ is not an upper bound of $B(r)$. Therefore $b^r$ must be the least upper bound of $B(r)$, and $b^r = \sup B(r)$

$$q.e.d$$

---

Are there any logical errors in my proof? Is it fairly rigorous?

Comment: The reasoning is correct, only that maybe when you say "it follows" and "it is clear", you may be asked to elaborate more in examinations (I've understood, I can tell you that).

Comment: If r isn't rational then there is no max.  I assume this question is chapter 1, 6 cl of baby rudin.  And that r is rational.  You haven't shown that max exists and if it does why b^r > = b^s.  Why can't b ^s > b^r.

Comment: Spend one or two sentences to prove for b > 1 and for rational positive r,s that r < s iff b^r < b^s.

Comment: I'm in disagreement with you about what is "clear".  If max exists (for any set), I think it is clear that max = sup. (It's greater or equal to all, and being IN the set anything smaller isn't a biund)  But it's not at all clear to me that max exists and that if it did that it'd be b^r.

Comment: @fleabood, Let me try to elaborate, since $b^r \in B(r)$, and $B(r) := \{b^t  \ | \ t, r \in \mathbb{Q} \ \land \ t \leq r \}$, it seems to me that $\max(B(r))$ has to be $b^r$, because any element $a \in B(r)$ is less than $b^r$. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Why is any element in B (r) less than b^r?  Simply choose a b^s > b^r where s < r.  Like I said, I think you should spend 1 or 2 sentences showing that is impossible.  It's a disagreement.  The proof requires two things: showing b^r in B (r) which is trivial.  And that b^r > = all B (r) which you think is clear and I don't. I think it is "clear" that an upper bound in a set is least upper bound and you don't need to show other upper bounds are larger.  It's minor and just my opinion.